# Can access key be used when an IAM role is attached to it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Credentials are automatically supplied to an ec2 instance when an IAM role is attached to it.

I have an ec2 instance running in an opsworks stack. It has an IAM role associated with it: **opsworks-ec2-role**. This role does not have permission to perform **iam:GetUser**.

I'm trying to export access keys(for a user having access to iam:GetUser) using ~/.aws/credentials file.

But it is still making request using iam role. I get error arn:aws:sts:::assumed-role/opsworks-ec2-role/ is not authorized to perform: iam:GetUser.

So is there a way to make request using the access key of the user rather than the instance role without removing the iam role from the instance(role is being assigned from opsworks stack & layer)?

Comment: Are you using awscli or a Python script with boto3, or something else? If the first two, then the order in which credentials are discovered is listed at http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/configuration.html. Note that instance profile is #8 on that list, so there are many options for overriding the credentials used.

Comment: I'm using awscli. It was not working. I tried it with a diff instance without any role, it worked.

Comment: Works perfectly here. I launched an EC2 instance with an EC2 read-only role, verified that awscli could describe EC2 instances but *not* list S3 buckets (aws s3 ls resulted in AccessDenied). Then I added a set of S3 read-only credentials to ~/.aws/credentials on the instance and was then able to list S3 buckets using aws s3 ls. So, it does work as documented. Something else is going on here.

Comment: It's possible the awscli command is running as a different user than the one with the `.aws/credentials` file. Perhaps it is running as root?

Comment: @MarkB I think it is possible

Comment: @AnkitDeshpande Well then you need to configure the AWS credentials for the user that the command is actually running as. Or specify the credentials through some other means such as environment variables.